# set default directory of "Open Workspace from File" in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open a workspace in vscode, I always have to navigate to ~/vscode-workspaces.  I wonder if I can choose the default directory it looks for workspace files in.

(I checked in settings and searched for 'folder' and 'directory' but didn't find anything appropriate.)

Comment: have you looked in the menu **File** > **Open Recent**